# How to hide drupal error message - one or more problems were detected with your drupal installation

Tags: 7

On logging on to Drupal administration page, I get an error message:

> One or more problems were detected with your drupal installation.

I've tried disabling modules.

Is there a way to hide this message?

Comment: It can be also a deactivated module, that was the problem on my drupal installation after the activation, i got updates for it and updated it and then the error was gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you reported is caused by a module that implements `hook_requirements()` to check if some conditions are verified. Instead of hiding the message, you should check what caused the error message by visiting the "Status report" page, where the module that caused the error message to appear will explain the cause of the error.

Keep in mind that also Drupal core modules cause the error to appear, for example when you need to run the module updates to update the database tables used by a module.

Answer (score 3):

You could check the status report and try to resolve the error but I guess you are happy to leave it that way.

Or you could hide the message by selecting the class and choosing not to display it using CSS.
Create a file called style.css in your "Theme" folder (alongside the location of page.tpl.php) and place the class within it (you can check the class by using Firebug/Inspector "right click on it, then inspect element").

I think the class will be .warning or .alert, and an example CSS code would be:

```
div.warning, .alert, div.error, tr.error
{
display:none;
}
```

This would however hide all alerts and warnings for elements with the same class.  So be careful because you could miss other critical notifications.  You could have a style sheet for non-admin users that would turn this off and another for admin areas that would display these messages.  Its your choice.

Comment: oh and make sure you flush all caches and run cron.

Comment: It's absolutely not the right action to do, you need to fix the issue instead of just hiding it.

Comment: I suggested he look at the status report and try to fix the issue, but the question that was asked was any way to hide these messages? There are many valid reasons why a developer might want to hide these messages from certain users, and I pointed that out.  Also for someone on shared hosting it may not be possible to go into MYSQL and clear out tables that have been left by disabled modules in the database.  It is always best to fix errors, but the question implied he wanted to disable the error message.

Comment: i really wanted to get rid of the error message somehow, havent done much in drupal so did nt know the details, or wat all was possible.. thats y i put the question in that way..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding these errors, you should configure properly corresponding modules...

Anyway, you can simply hide these errors in Site configuration > Error reporting (no need to add css rule for this).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it temporarily: Go to admin/settings/error-reporting and change the *Error reporting* setting to *Write errors to log*.

The [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module shows the errors only to administrator users.

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end users. The core Drupal message system as offered by `drupal_set_message()` is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users. However, not all Drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages sent out by Drupal core and all modules to their users. This module gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out messages shown to the end users.

I know you need to fix these errors. Meanwhile, all your site users see these red messages. They don't affect anyone except logged-in users, normally, and they may be completely minor.
I got many errors about the need of doing a security update, but the site worked normally. It's different when typical users are logged in, but in my case, I'm the only user and only administrator (except for the site designers who designed the site for me).
In a situation like this, the last thing you want is showing error messages to the visitors who are only interested to the content shown after the error messages. That could mean losing all your sales for one day or for several days if you happen to be on holiday.